# help with 960 grid and jquery

Tags: jquery, css, 960.gs

Doing this as a class group project, I'm doing the front end while other members are doing the backend. I'm using the 24 columns 960 grid system, to try and position everything. It is my first time really doing a project using CSS and the 960 grid system.

I'm using javascript to include other html files.Excluding the header and footer, I created 6 divs for the main content area and want each div to include a different html file. 2 Rows of 3 divs.

The problem I have come across is that the divs are stacking ontop of each other and I cant really control how wide each div is even though i gave it a grid_8 class. On top of that they are stacking ontop of each other, and it gets cut off at the bottom even after I scroll down. I also want to make the footer stay at the bottom but instead of being fixed on the bottom of the browser at all times I want to scroll all the way down to be able to see it.

Here is what it looks like atm, I gave borders to the divs so you can see how they are stacking http://i53.tinypic.com/2lbzgp.png I have also put `<div id="clear"></div>` into the **header.html** and **footer.html** files

Any help is appreciated, been driving me nuts for the past week.

**EDITED again** Don't know if I did this right, but here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/RZtXu/3/

Comment: I'm using javascript to include other html files. <-- why?

Comment: it would also help if you can post your html and css(and you js) code here: http://jsfiddle.net and give us a link so we can play around with it. and welcome to SO

Comment: @corroded the guy doing the backend stock tracker insisted it, i was originally going to use php to call the header and footers.  Sorry I forgot to attach the code been meaning to do so, but been staying up really late lately trying to fix this thing so I'm not thinking straight.  Thanks for the link I'll get onto it now.  Though the file is a .jsp file and not a html file I don't know if that matters

Comment: edited post with code from jsfiddle

Comment: Wow... there is still people doing `.jsp` pages!! You should move on, that's sooo 80's :o)

Comment: @balexandre I don't know javascript so I'm just doing what that guy tells me to do and I'm basically supposed to just make sure everything looks good and is in the proper place.

Comment: can you paste the generated html instead of your html code in? your fiddle doesn't show anything helpful as of now

Comment: done http://jsfiddle.net/RZtXu/3/

Comment: they're not stacking in your jsfiddle...wasnt that the problem?

Comment: well i think the javascripts not running so the table doesnt appear like in the screen shot attatched, and still the divs are not in the correct positions.(ie topright is under topleft and ontop of bottom left).  When I run the tomcat server and check local host it looks like [this](http://i53.tinypic.com/2lbzgp.png)

Comment: also the payment methods div doesn't show up for me when I run it off localhost

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark due to lack of code but are you using a wrapper div with class container-24?

Comment: yes I am, I'm trying to use that jsfiddle thing but it seems like the CSS section has a character limit of some sort

Comment: @Clyde Lobo theres no where to put CSS in there, but i already edited the post to include the code

Comment: well you can, using the `<style>` tag

Comment: Thanks, this helped me figure out why the 960 grid wasn't rendering in a jquery dialog popup!